# Creating REDIS cluster on OpenShift

Tags: docker, redis, kubernetes, openshift, redhat

I'm using [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) image and have created two REDIS deployments on OpenShift.
Deployment names are `redis-node01` and `redis-node02`.
I have also created minimal REDIS cluster configuration file, as described [here](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial).
It looks like this, and its loaded at REDIS startup:

```
port 7000
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
```

Now I open the terminal of one of the REDIS containers, and issue cluster meet command, as described [here](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-meet). I get this error:

```
(error) ERR Invalid node address specified: redis-node02:6379
```

I suppose that REDIS cant contact another instance on that address? How to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you get for ``oc get services``? If everything is in the same project, then each should be able to contact the others using the service name as the hostname.

Comment: @graham-dumpleton Yes, I do have services defined... <br/>
`redis-node02 172.30.152.122 none 6372/TCP, 16372/TCP`<br/>
`redis-node01 172.30.204.64 none 6379/TCP, 16379/TCP`<br/>

I have started REDIS on two different ports, and exposes a The cluster bus port as suggested in cluster tutorial. This still doesn't help.

Comment: As you can see it says `redis-node02:6379` when it should be `redis-node02:6372`. So your cluster config is not correct I assume

Comment: How did you deploy the redis instances? Using web console or oc new-app? They will pick up ports from EXPOSE definition in image. Or did you manually create the JSON/YAML for resources, including creating the service object yourself which specifies which ports are exposed?

Comment: @ Tarun Lalwani yes, you are correct, but I changed the configuration of the ports after my original question. Sorry for the confusion.

@Graham Dumpleton I deployed them using web console. I'm aware they pick up EXPOSE definition of the image, but I changed their definition afterwards in YAML, as well as ports which REDIS listens on... I have succeeded to create a cluster when I issued the command with the service IP, but that still doesn't solve the problem as that can change dynamically.

Comment: You shouldn't use the service IP, you would use ``redis-node02`` and ``redis-node01`` as a hostname in place of IP.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton, yes but then it doesn't work, as I explained in the question.

Comment: Have you used ``oc rsh`` to get into the pod and see what IP those hostnames resolve to? Is Redis listening on all interfaces, ie., ``0.0.0.0``, for requests?

Comment: Since ``dig`` and ``nslookup`` probably aren't in an image, you may be able to do ``python -c 'import socket;  print(socket.gethostbyaddr("redis-node02"))'``

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no python in a REDIS image (https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/)... Additionally, I tried to deploy a REDIS container using hostNetwork set to true, and that doesn't help also....  It looks like I'm out of options here.

Comment: hello dplesa, Wondering if you have already a solution for this ?

Comment: @theG, unfortunately no